# Делать сложные запросы или обрабатывать данные в скрипте?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, база-данных, веб-программирование

Допустим, есть база данных и две таблицы: счета и транзакции.

Поля таблицы «счета»:

1) Id 
2) Общая сумма 
3) Номер счёта

Поля таблицы «транзакции»:

1) Id 
2) Сумма 
3) Тип транзакции (входящий или исходящий) 
4) Id счёта

Вывести хочу общую ведомость в таком формате:

```
Id счета | Общая сумма | Сумма исходящих | Сумма входящих | Разница
```

Такую таблицу можно сделать сразу на SQL. Нужно будет два раза сделать join для таблицы с транзакциями. Первый раз для подсчёта входящей суммы, второй раз для подсчёта исходящей суммы.

Но можно сделать общую таблицу в таком виде, и обработать данные в скрипте:

```
Id счёта | Общая сумма | Тип транзакции | Сумма транзакции
```

Join получится один, но таблицу придётся дополнительно обрабатывать в скрипте и считать суммы в нём.

Как правильно делать с точки зрения ресурсов?

Comment: Если у вас БД на мейнфрейме, а скрипты - на ПК, то лучше через БД. Если наоборот - то наоборот. Универсального совета нет - попробуйте и так, и так и оцените скорость

Comment: И скрипты и база на сервере. Какова общая практика? Как делают обычно?

Comment: Обычно  испытывают на практике. Разные СУБД, как и разные языки, работают по-разному. Если СУДБ "рядом" передача больших данных не проблема, можно обрабатывать в скрипте. Если потом захочется БД "отделить" - скажется пропускная способность канала связи. Вопрос слишком общий. Единого ответа не дать...

Comment: В БД обычно делают. Тянуть все данные для подсчета на клиента затратно даже в пределах одной машины, куча лишних копирований одного и того же. Тем более, что запрос достаточно простой и два join совершенно не нужно. `sum(if(тип-транзакции = 'входящая', Сумма, 0))` и рядом аналогичный sum с условием для исходящей

Comment: Хотя немного не дочитал вопрос. Да, с группировкой по типу транзакции и разворачивании на клиенте в горизонталь все становится не так очевидно, по сети гонится практически такой же объем данных, а затраты времени по развороту, при правильной сортировке минимальны. Но как я и сказал выше проще получить сразу в нужном формате применив условное суммирование

Comment: И кстати, если нужен только id-счета и суммарные данные то в запросе ни одного join не нужно, все выбирается за один проход по второй таблице :)

Comment: @Mike, спасибо за развёрнутый ответ. Таблицы привел из головы для примера) Естественно, в действительности запросы посложнее. Хотелось узнать общеупотребимую практику. Как делают в лучших домах Лондона и Парижа)